# Pythonic way of iterating over an array and remove all None

Tags: python, for-loop

My statements looks like the following:

```
[future.result() for future in as_completed(futures)]
```

It works, except that, at times, `future.result()` resolved to `None`, which puts `None` into my array. How can I discard these `None`s? Something similar to

```
[if future.result() is not None: future.result() for future in as_completed(futures)]
```

Comment: `[future.result() for future in as_completed(futures) if future.result() is not None]`?

Comment: What Julien said. However, if the `future.result()` method is expensive to compute (or has side-effects) it would be better to do this in two stages. First create a list (or generator) of all the results and then filter out the `None`s.

Comment: Further to @PM remark, read on https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *force* the removal of `None` from the return of `future.result` into a single list comprehension by using a nested *for*, calling the function **once**:

```
[x for future in as_completed(futures) 
   for x in (future.result(),) if x is not None]
```

However, it is more **readable** to filter the `None` values from the list after the first comprehension completes:

```
lst = [future.result() for future in as_completed(futures)]
final_list = [x for x in lst if x is not None]
```

Comment: Similar approach: `final_result = filter(lambda _: _ is not None, lst)`

Comment: @Julien Yes, works the same, however, note that `filter` returns an iterator, not a list in Python 3.

Comment: Also, a `filter` that requires a `lambda` (or Python level `def`) is slower (in all versions) than an equivalent listcomp/genexpr that avoids function calls, and generally less readable to boot.

Comment: To avoid a potentially large intermediate `list`, you might change the first listcomp to a genexpr, so you only make one final `list`.

Comment: Of course, you can avoid passing a `lambda` to `filter` if `None` is the only False-ish value returned by `future.result()`.